# Send json from Python script to Node-red locally

Tags: python, node-red

I currently have a Python script sending data over to an IoT Hub and a node in a Node-red flow receiving that information, but for some cases that would not work (ex. when internet is down).

[image]

I'm wondering if there is any way I can adapt my Python script to get that json object sent directly to Node-red bypassing any communication over the Internet.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a really easy to find question as its even in the Python docs, but what you are looking for is Requests. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Had seen it, but it goes through HTTP which requires it to be online then right?

Comment: The Python script has to be able to reach where ever the Node-red server is. It doesn't need to be over the internet though.

Comment: Okay, so then in my Python script I'll send the json object over to "127.0.0.1:1800" for instance, what URL should I add in the HTTP input node? I'm a bit lost in the topic, sorry for the simple questions.

Comment: I sugget you read https://cookbook.nodered.org/http/create-an-http-endpoint

Answer (score 0):

You could add in a messaging solution in the middle. You would use something like a Python MQi library, which would be able to provide you with assured message delivery at the Python end when the network connection re-establishes. There are a varied set of MQ and MQRest Node-RED nodes that you can use on the Node-RED end listening for messages.